# named entities recognition using stanfordNERTagger

Tags: computational-linguistics, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to get the named entities in a small test using stanford NER tagger. Here is the code:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser')
print st.tag('Ram offers computer science course'.split())
```

Output I get is:

```
[(u'Ram', u'O'), (u'offers', u'O'), (u'computer', u'O'), (u'science', u'O'), (u'course', u'O')]
```

I am not getting why all the tags are 'O'. While Ram is a person, Computer is an object,science and course are also classifiable objects.

Is there any way I can get named entities for my sentence Like below:

```
Ram -> Person
Coputer Science -> Course
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

no tool is perfect. It seems, that Stanford NER with the default model (no specific training) does not recognise *Ram* as a personal name and that is is also agnostic about course titles.

You may train it (or just add Ram to its dictionary) to get *Ram* right. I am not sure whether you can add categories of named entities like courses and how much effort this will take.